# php include_path error - pulling from servers include path and not user's path

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a cpanel account on a shared server and I am having an issue using context_document_root because it is trying to pull the files from the actual server's include_path and not my specific user accounts include path.  I need to figure out what is going on.

Here is the error:

```
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/WMS/configuration.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/kylej/public_html/index.php on line 4
```

The file is located in  public_html/WMS/configuration.php and is actually there.

In my htaccess: I've added `RewriteBase /~kylej/` and I even tried creating a php.ini file inside my root directory with `ini_set('include_path', '/home/kylej/public_html');` in it.

Can someone please help?

Inside the .php file, here is my include: `include_once($_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/WMS/configuration.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, `$_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is resolving to a `null` / empty value. This is why you shouldn't add external dependencies to your app.

Use a path relative to `__DIR__` instead, thus keeping your app portable.

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/WMS/configuration.php';
```

In `/home/kylej/public_html/index.php`, `__DIR__` will resolve to `/home/kylej/public_html`.

Also, enabling proper error reporting and display would have alerted you to the fact that `$_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not set.

Comment: The issue with this at this point is that if I am using this sitewide; how do I make it always equal /home/kylej/public_html if I am needing to use absolute path when inside another folder and including files from root directory.